# What programs exist to find and delete "orphan files" left after deleting an Application?

Tags: software-recommendation, utilities, applications, macos

I have transferred my system from Mac to Mac for over 15 years. I have preference files and other plists lurking around in my system for programs I tested years ago.

Is there a smart program that could point me to these orphan files knowing that the application that created them is not on my system?

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to use Terminal.app you can use `find` to identify files/folders which haven't been accessed for a long time.

- `find ~/Library/Preferences -atime +52w` will list all prefences which haven't been accessed in the last 52 weeks.
- `find -d ~/Library/Preferences -atime +52w -ok rm '{}' \;` will ask whether you want to delete it file by file

and if you don't want to get asked for each file, run

```
find -d ~/Library/Preferences -atime +52w -delete
```

Comment: Correct, although the task is a bit more difficult as I don't want to remove files belonging to an actual program on my computer. Mixing what you say with the answer of CraftyThumber, I might come up with a pretty good solution. Let's see what my scripting can do !

Comment: How to run this command without typying `y` all the time?

Comment: @konrad see updated answer

Answer (score 6):

[OnyX](http://www.onyxmac.com/) has several cleaning options and might be worth a try.

Other than that, you could check the installation receipts in `/Library/Receipts` and `~/Library/Receipts`. Applications that are installed via installers should write to this directory with what they've installed and where. You could inspect this for programs that you've *'uninstalled'* and manually remove the lurking files.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of these "receipts". Very interesting. I might develop a little tool for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Barth: I'd be interested in the result if you manage it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not connected to the company but if you want a paid app In the past I have used [App Zapper.](http://appzapper.com)

It is a drag and drop app. You drag the app to the window and it shows all dependencies for you to delete or not. I did a clean install for ML so I haven't used it in quite some time and I'm afraid I don't recall the cost but I remember it was not expensive.
UPDATE: It cost $12.95; More than I remembered.

Perhaps [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com) could be used; Open the uninstalled version of the app in Pacifist (drag it there) and look to see what gets installed, then remove those items?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, as I said, the application that created the files is not anymore on my system. Appzapper is good for deinstalling programs though.

Answer (score 2):

We can see the apps previously installed in our macOS with a terminal command:

`ls -la /private/var/db/receipts/`

Then we can use their codename to locate related files:

`mdfind [app_name]`